# Installing Software with dynamic code using a Template based on user-selected options

Tags: c#, templates, chatbot

I want to write something but I need to know if it’s possible in theory. I want an install file that calls to a GitHub repo based on options the user selects during install process. Currently the program components written can make over 131k unique combinations and that’s just too many packages to compile, maintain, and update on any kind of regular basis. It has to be in c# because of the framework I’m using so is that possible to create a template that the GitHub code pulls fill in and then compile on the client. I could build one package with a bunch of if-thens but I’m worried about the sheer size of something like that.

The code template would be hardcoded with code that is universal to all options. The code pulls from GitHub would be used to fill in the gaps. For example:

Function:
Look up info from [JIRA KB OR SNOW KB OR LOCAL KB]
Code that does a thing
Update a servicE ticket in [SNOW OR JIRA]

Comment: Sounds more like a combination of nugets.  Like libs that support different dbs. They'd have a core nuget and then somelib.sqlite and somelib.mysql ...